# Using a classifier's test error as a model evaluation metric for another model

Tags: multi-class, multilabel, model-evaluation

I have a multi-class multi-label (MCML) dataset, built from a model I do not trust (assume I am right for distrusting it). Say I have 1000 patients with 14 feature scores, and 5 possible target labels - of which each patient can qualify for greater than or equal to one of those labels.

X = 14 features: {x1, x2, ..., x14}
Y = 5 target labels: {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5}

Because I do not trust the model, I do not trust all of the labels the model I am examining, outputs. I want to perform an experiment, where I *evaluate* the reasonability of a model built from the dataset I distrust, *but with one of the target labels in the label set deleted*.

I will thus have 5 experiments, where I delete only one of the target labels from the set {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5}. For example:

```
Expt 1: X = {x1,x2,...x14}, Y={y2,y3,y4,y5}
Expt 2: X = {x1,x2,...x14}, Y={y1,y3,y4,y5}
Expt 3: X = {x1,x2,...x14}, Y={y1,y2,y4,y5}
Expt 4: X = {x1,x2,...x14}, Y={y1,y2,y3,y5}
Expt 5: X = {x1,x2,...x14}, Y={y1,y2,y3,y4}
```

To evaluate each model, I compare how well a multi class multi label learner was able to learn the dataset (i.e, using various evaluation metrics for multi-label learners).

Is it reasonable to use a machine learning classifier to judge the reasonability of a partial of a given model, compared to other partial models? As long as the target score vector's dimensionality is the same, I see no reason why this would be illogical.

Also, is this a roundabout way of doing this? Perhaps there is a statistical technique that examines partial models built from a multi-class multi-label dataset which can tell me which labels are not informative?

Comment: I think you are trying to construct a sort of a stacked classifier (constructing a new virtual training set from existing classifier predictions). However, did I understand it right that you are not interrested in all predictions of the existing model?